# Assign Same SNo to Parent and its Child

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Table With name "TmpTable", this table have the Parent Child Relationship, table have data look like:

```
Id | Name      | ParentId
 1   PCs         0
 2   MACs        1
 3   Keyboard    0
 4   Mouse       0
 5   Screen      3
 6   Keyboard    4
 7   Mouse       0
 8   Screen      0
 9   Key         0          
 10  xyz         9
```

Now I want to Select One Column With this Which shows the Sequence Number, in that Parent and Child have the Same S.No. and which did not have any child have Increased S.No., result will be same as below:

```
Id | Name      | ParentId | SNo
 1   PCs         0           1  
 2   MACs        1           1
 3   Keyboard    0           2
 4   Mouse       0           3
 5   Screen      3           2
 6   Keyboard    4           3
 7   Mouse       0           4
 8   Screen      0           5
 9   Key         0           6
 10  xyz         9           6
```

How can I archive this result please Guide/help me in this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`DENSE_RANK()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) function in combination with `ORDER BY CASE`:

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN ParentID = 0 THEN ID ELSE ParentID END) 
FROM TmpTable
ORDER BY Id
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76120/10)**

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this.

```
;with cte as 
(Select Row_Number() Over(Order by Id) as Row,Id from Table1 where Parentid=0
)
Select A.*,b.row as Sno from Table1 A inner join
cte as b on b.id=a.parentid or (b.id=a.id and a.parentid=0) order by a.id;
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d88cc/12)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full-blown solution for n-depth:

```
;WITH src AS (
    SELECT id=1, pid=0
    UNION ALL SELECT id=2, pid=1
    UNION ALL SELECT id=3, pid=0
    UNION ALL SELECT id=4, pid=0
    UNION ALL SELECT id=5, pid=3
    UNION ALL SELECT id=6, pid=4
    UNION ALL SELECT id=7, pid=0
    UNION ALL SELECT id=8, pid=0
    UNION ALL SELECT id=9, pid=0
    UNION ALL SELECT id=10, pid=9
),
rcte AS (
    SELECT id, pid, sno = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) 
    FROM src WHERE pid=0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.id, s.pid, r.sno
    FROM 
        rcte r
        JOIN src s 
            ON s.pid = r.id
    WHERE s.pid != 0 
)
SELECT *
FROM rcte
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done via a `JOIN`. I thought this could be helpful for MYSQL as it does not have window functions

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT 
  m1.id,
  m1.name,
  m1.parentid,
  1 + count( m2.id ) as sno
FROM
  mytable m1 
  LEFT JOIN mytable m2 on ( ( m1.parentid = 0 AND m2.parentid = 0 AND m2.id < m1.id)
                              OR ( m2.parentid = 0 AND m2.id < m1.parentid ) )
GROUP BY
  m1.id,
  m1.name,
  m1.parentid
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b794f/8)

**Note:** It assumes that your parents are always have a `id` less than their `childs`